# How to animate 2D clouds in Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d-2dtools

I have 2D game and cloud sprites. I need to animate it. To clouds generate randomly e.g. in the left edge of the screen and move to the right edge of the screen. Clouds count must variate from 1 to 4 that can be visible on the screen simultaneously.
How can I do it? Just what do I need to use (write own script or Unity3D has a some tools already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a step by step guide to create randomly moving clouds in Unity

1. Create a prefab for the cloud sprite.
2. Create a new C# Script named CloudScript and Attach it to to the cloud prefab.
3. Add the code in this paste bin to the C# Script
   http://pastebin.com/iX41mDui
4. Create an empty object in the scene and name it CloudManager
5. Add the code in this paste bin to the C# Script http://pastebin.com/s5nYdwaV
6. Set the public values for both scripts through inspector, based on preferences. For recommended values look at comments in code.

After this the script should work and make the clouds move across the screen at random heights and random speeds. All the comments in the code should pretty much explain to you how the whole thing works.

Just in case you need it, here's an example project with all the code in action https://www.dropbox.com/s/728v8ilzcvwff6e/RandomCloudMovementProject.unitypackage?dl=0

Comment: Also if you need to also limit the number of clouds that can be on the screen each time just add an int that keeps track of the number of clouds on the screen, and then adjust the while loop that Instantiates the clouds to only run while that int is less than whatever number you want. In my opinion though, I think the delay works either just as good or even better, but it's your choice.

Comment: Yeah, I understood. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Actually, Thank you, I was really bored at like 11:00 at night, and saw your question, and I was like Yay! 5 min coding project! Anyways wish you luck on whatever you're working on.

Comment: Sorry, I too bad know English to understand all text.